# Syntax Missing ) when all ) seem to be there?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, innerhtml

Okay, so I've been building this website. One of the pages is a newsfeed www.wenotelling.x10.mx/news/
The news page has the newsfeed page embedded within it, which is where the actual updating happens. All that is very well and good, and that webpage seems to work. I was having 2 issues though.

1. The newsfeed didn't seem to update when the pages is loaded, but loads when the page is refreshed.
2. I wanted to add smileys.

So I wrote some JScript to fix both of these issues in one go. Since the newsfeed is updated through the HTML page, and I didn't want to have to hunt for the smiley's URL every time, I came up with the following code:
http://www.wenotelling.x10.mx/news/smilescript.js

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    alert("Called");
    document.getElementByClass('happy').innerHTML = '<img src="smileys/happy.gif"></img>';
    document.getElementByClass('star').innerHTML = '<img src="smileys/star.gif"></img>';
    document.getElementByClass('dead').innerHTML = '<img src="smileys/dead.gif"></img>';
    document.getElementByClass('yawn').innerHTML = '<img src="smileys/yawn.gif"></img>';
    document.getElementByClass('snub').innerHTML = '<img src="smileys/snub.gif"></img>';
    document.getElementByClass('relax').innerHTML = '<img src="smileys/relax.gif"></img>';
    document.getElementByClass('devil').innerHTML = '<img src="smileys/devil.gif"></img>';
    document.getElementByClass('cool').innerHTML = '<img src="smileys/cool.gif"></img>';
    document.getElementByClass('wink').innerHTML = '<img src="smileys/wink.gif"></img>';
    document.getElementByClass('shock').innerHTML = '<img src="smileys/shock.gif"></img>';
    document.getElementByClass('bigsmile').innerHTML = '<img src="smileys/bigsmile.gif"></img>';
    document.getElementByClass('confused').innerHTML = '<img src="smileys/confused.gif"></img>';
    document.getElementByClass('sad').innerHTML = '<img src="smileys/sad.gif"></img>';
    document.getElementByClass('angry').innerHTML = '<img src="smileys/angry.gif"></img>';
    document.getElementByClass('clown').innerHTML = '<img src="smileys/clown.gif"></img>';
    document.getElementByClass('blush').innerHTML = '<img src="smileys/blush.gif"></img>';
    if(location.hash !="#");
    {
        location = "#";
        location.reload(true);
    }
    alert("A-OK");
});
```

So, when editing we can simply put `<smiley class="happy"></smiley>`. I know smiley isn't a real tag, but I didn't think it'd make a difference because I've seen "faketags" before. I tried changing the smiley tag to `<div class="happy"></div>` but that didn't work either. At the end of the script, I put a refresh function.

Anyways, the script wasn't working. It's being called, but not working. So I ran it through
    Firebug. Firebug gave the following message:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error]   
(22 out of range 21)
```

I then looked at the script, and well, all of the ) seem to be there. Not only that, but the smileys prior to line 22 aren't working either.

Anyways. Any ideas why:
1) The Smileys aren't appearing?
2) The script isn't being fully executed?

Comment: `if(location.hash !="#")` not  `if(location.hash !="#");`

Comment: Why are you not using css-background images?

Comment: Also, is `location = "#";`  a valid assignment???

Comment: use an online syntax validation site like jslint or jshint... you would have isolated your own problems faster than writing your question

Comment: See how when you tab your code correctly the error will be immediately obvious

Comment: @A.V it is, but probably doesn't do what OP wants it to do

Comment: As @yoshi said: If you're working about *look* and *style* and setting `classes`, the right place to do that is `.css` files, through `background:` assignment.

Comment: +1: In general what helps me sometimes in those situations is to copy my script into jsFiddle.net like this http://jsfiddle.net/fRSJf/ and press the JSLint button. Which in this case told me `Problem at line 20 character 30: Expected '{' and instead saw ';'.`. It's a good start and works for myself when I don't have Visual Studio open with Re-sharper. I'm not trying to be smart or anything I just thought it might help you in the future as those little things can get very frustrating alright.

Comment: A.V and soulcheck: It's to prevent the frame from repeatedly refreshing.
charlietfl: Thanks for the tip about jslint. I'll see if I can find it later.
Yoshi: Simply? I'm new to this. I wasn't aware I could do it with CSS. 

Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the script you linked to, line #19:

```
if(location.hash !="#");{
```

That semi-colon shouldn't be there. (btw, the lines inside the `if` block should be indented)

Furthermore, there is no such a thing as `document.getElementsByClass`, only `document.getElementsByClassName`, and that returns a NodeList and not a single element (so changing its `innerHTML` won't do much.)

Other notes:

- In your website, you are including `css/stylesheet.css` twice (lines #4 and #12), and actually 3 times, if you count the one inside the iframe.
- The jquery version you're using is incredibly outdated, and the inclusion of jquery is hardly justified in this case - you're just using it to do a `$(document).ready`, which can be done without jquery if you ether stick a (semi-close) `window.onload` listener, or just put the script close to the `</body>`
- As said in the comments, and I couldn't agree more, don't just stick images inside those elements. Add an appropriate CSS class, and let CSS handle it.

Comment: I'm including my stylesheet twice? Line 12 includes the Nav Bar... does that re-include the stylesheet then? Anyways, I'll take a look into doing it with CSS.

Comment: Sorry, line #13; on line #12 of the source is where where you also re-open `<html>` and `<head>`. Do a view-source on the page.

Comment: Ahh. I see what I did now. Originally I had the navigation bar as an iFrame. Obviously, that isn't going to work, so I changed it to a .php. The stylesheet was included in the .php as well, along with the reopening of the head and html.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes javascript errors are a bit misleading, but at least one syntax error can be spotted in your code:

```
 if(location.hash !="#");{
```

has an extra `;`. Maybe that's the reason.

Btw, since you're using jQuery anyway, why not use it for element selection and html content setting?

Answer (score 0):

A couple things you should immediately fix would be a call to a non-existent method, and a stray-semicolon. The first is your call to `getElementByClass`, which is singular rather than plural. And Secondly, you have a semicolon out of place here: `if(location.hash !="#");`.

Since you're using jQuery, I'd encourage you to avoid native methods like `getElementsByClass`, since that doesn't exist in some older browsers. Instead, try something like this:

```
var emoticons = ["happy","star","dead","yawn"];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.each(emoticons, function (index, value) {
        $("<img>", {src: "smileys/" + value + ".gif"}).appendTo("." + value);
    });
});​
```

Note here how we don't repeat ourselves over and over for each emoticon. I would encourage you to look into sprites, since they generally work far better as a solution for problems like this. But that's for another day.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yRSF9/